# Botón después de vídeo

Tags: php, jquery, html5

He subido un vídeo de vimeo a mi página y cuando finalice tiene que aparecer un botón de descarga.

Éste es mi código, el botón esta incluido.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    @ini_set("session.use_trans_sid","0");
    @ini_set("session.use_only_cookies","1");
    @session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", $HTTP_SERVER_VARS["HTTP_HOST"], 0);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        header('LOCATION:index.php'); die();
    }
    //session_destroy();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reinvent Web</title> 
         <link href="../static/css/pcexperience.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="reinvent">
        <img class="pcexperience" src="../images/reinvent.png">
        <div class="letras">
                <ul>
                <li><a class="r" href="pcexperience.php"><img src="../images/r.png"></a></li>
                <li><a class="e" href="pcexperience-video02.php"><img src="../images/e.png"></a></li>
                <li><a class="i" href="pcexperience-video03.php"><img  src="../images/i.png"></a> </li>
                <li><a class="n" href="pcexperience-video04.php"><img src="../images/n.png"></a> </li>
                <li><a class="v" href="pcexperience-video05.php"><img  src="../images/v.png"></a></li> 
                <li><a class="e02" href="pcexperience-video06.php"><img src="../images/e.png"></a></li>  
                <li><a class="n02" href="pcexperience-video07.php"><img  src="../images/n.png"></a></li>
                <li><a class="t" href="pcexperience-video08.php"><img src="../images/t.png"></a></li>
                </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
        <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe id="video-r" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/297720699?autoplay=1" width="1400" height="600" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
<div class="boton">
        <a href="../descargas/Congresos_LATAM.pptx" download><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button></a>
        </div>      
    </div>


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Santiago. Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprnder el funcionamiento del sitio. Necesitas pulsar en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta añadiendo exactamente qué problema tienes. Mira [ask] y  [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

para ello,tienes que usar la librería javascript que proporciona Vimeo para poder realizar tal tarea.He hecho un ejemplo sencillo para que lo entiendas.El botón lo creo al vuelo,creándolo en ese Div cuando finalize el video.Prueba el codigo JavaScript en tu página,verás como funciona.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var jqueryPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('video-r');
    
  var intervalo = setInterval(function(){
   jqueryPlayer.getEnded().then(function(ended) {
    if(ended){
     $("#videoDiv").append('<a href="../descargas/Congresos_LATAM.pptx" download><button     class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button></a>');
     clearInterval(intervalo);
    }
       
   }).catch(function(error) {
        
  });
 },100);    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="video">
        <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe id="video-r" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/297720699?autoplay=1" width="400" height="600" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boton" id="videoDiv"> </div>    


</body>
</html>
```